# Print the output in ascending order of the packet count

Tags: c, sorting, printing, structure

I have a small C code snippet as shown below:

```
    static void results(void)
   {
    int id;
    uint64_t packets, bytes;

    packets = 0;
    bytes = 0;

    if (x->option)
    {
            printf("\n App    Packets     Bytes");
            printf("\n --------------------------------\n");
    }

    for (id = 0; id < x->config_num_proto; id++)
    {
            if (x->option)
            {
                    if (x->packets)
                    {

                            printf(" %-12s%-12" PRIu64 "%" PRIu64 "\n", x->name
                                    , x->packets, x->bytes);
                    }
            }

         packets += x->packets;
         bytes += x->bytes;

     }

     printf("\n")

  }
```

The output looks like below:

```
  App  Packets   Bytes

  AB     312      44922

  CD      5        863

  EF      18      2160

  GH      9        574

  ..      ..        ..
  ..      ..        ..
```

My objective is to print out the output in the same way except the packets should be in ascending order. I am fairly new to C so unable to think of something tricky and small which can give me the desired output. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: A simple method is put all your `x's` into an array and call `bsearch()` to sort them out.  But there is too much missing from your example to provide a detailed answer.

Comment: Oops - I meant to say `qsort()` not `bsearch()`.  It's late.  Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use qsort to sort your array before you start your loop.  Without knowing what type X is I can't actually write the code.

Also, you're not every changing x, so I'm not sure why you'd ever see any differences.

Assuming X is a pointer into an array called "data" which is of type "thing"

int packetSorter (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  if (((thing*)a)->packets > ((thing*)b)->packets)
    return 1;
  else if (((thing*)a)->packets == ((thing*)b)->packets)
    return 0;
  else
    return -1;
}

then call qsort:

qsort(data, sizeof(thing), number_of_thingss_in_data, packetSorter);

Now, when you go through your data array, it will be sorted.

Comment: 'X' is a pointer to a structure which contains three members, packets, bytes and name of the App

Comment: The only thing I am unable to figure out is how do I create an array consisting of App, Packets and Bytes. I think having just Packets in the array can also do the trick.

Comment: you have an array of structs, so you already have those things, hence the ->packets